# yii2 gridview filters with beforeValidate() values

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have a yii2 GridView, as generated by gii CRUD.

I point my browser to `/model/index`. I **do not** include any search values in the GET string. But the GridView filter comes pre-populated with values.
[image]

Even if I try to delete or replace these filter-values, the pre-populated values spring back.

I am noticing that these prepopulated-values come from the model's `beforeValidate()` method.

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
    if (parent::beforeValidate()) {
        if ($this->isNewRecord) {
            $this->created_at = time();
            $this->b_soft_deleted = 0;
        }
        $this->updated_at = time();
        return true;
    }           
    return false;
}
```

Evidently, the GridView Filter calls `beforeValidate()` and the uses these values for a filter...

- Why is this happening?
- What can I do to get a clean slate for filter values?

(Running yii2 2.0.10 on php 7.0.14)

**update** My Search Model is

```
<?php

namespace common\models\generated;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use common\models\Article;

/**
 * ArticleSearch represents the model behind the search form about     `common\models\Article`.
 */
class ArticleSearch extends Article
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'title', 'description', 'positive_keywords', 'negative_keywords'], 'safe'],
        [['created_at', 'updated_at', 'b_soft_deleted'], 'integer'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Article::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'b_soft_deleted' => $this->b_soft_deleted,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'id', $this->id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->title])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'description', $this->description])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'positive_keywords', $this->positive_keywords])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'negative_keywords', $this->negative_keywords]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show your search model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting attributes in `beforeValidate()` which are applied when `$this->validate()` is called (no matter the validation result).

You need to move this set somewhere else or...

If I'm guessing correctly you do set `created_at` and `updated_at` because these fields are marked as **not null** in your database and because of that gii generated `required` rules for them.
The proper way of dealing with such attributes is to remove the `required` rule for them and add `yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior` that takes care of setting them on model save step.
This way you don't see validation errors for the model and don't have to set these manually and database columns are filled properly.

And this whole GridView problem is gone.

Comment: Yes, you are guessing correct. I will work this around to a `TimestampBehavior`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [**Bizley**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3364821/bizley) solution, we also may not use TimestampBehavior, just we should cancel the required and then place that logic in `beforeSave`. This is more general solution if you would like to do any logic or creating some pre-made values.